# javascript scrolling youtube player, modifying divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, youtube

this is my first post on here, but I've found this site extremely helpful in the past, it is my go-to when I do a google search.

I run a how-to youtube channel. I've finished building my webpages and they are mostly ready to go online, but I need to have descriptions along with each video that appear as it is clicked. I'm using [this responsive player](http://www.woosterwebdesign.com/responsive-youtube-player-with-playlist/), I've been trying to modify the HTML and DIVs so that there is also a description that appears to the right of each video, with the thumbnails also below it. I tried using getElementsByIDs instead of getElementByID, but that just broke everything (unless I didn't do something right), so I deleted that and tried using another getElementByID tag. I experimented with a separate video from the demo just to get it working.

This is what I did. Basically all I did was mimic the divs for the "vid-container" div and renamed it to a "vid-desc-container", then placed it directly below the "vid-container" div in the html code. Then I made new divs with similar properties except for the placement. The result? It worked, but the second video div was directly below the first. If I can get the placement on the right (2/3 the size of the video, but also above the scrolling thumbnails) then I can put a description in instead. I apologize if the HTML isn't legible, I tried to but it wouldn't paste into this post without breaking.

The demo was set to adjust to screen width and scale down to mobile platforms, but I disabled that and I'll just be redirecting to a mobile version of the site where I won't have a description.

I put my edited html file from the demo (demo is in the link above) in my dropbox. If you replace their html file with the one I have in [this dropbox link][2] then you'll see how I modified it. I keep trying to paste the code into this original post but it is cutting off some parts.

This is what I added in

```
<DIV class="vid-desc-container"><IFRAME width="560" height="315" id="vid_desc" src="Demo%20Responsive%20YouTube%20Player%20with%20Scrolling%20Thumbnail%20Playlist_files/eg6kNoJmzkY.htm"
```

frameborder="0">

I also added this to the css, I played around with "left" and couldn't get it to position where I wanted.

```
        .vid-desc-container embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
```

and I also modified the first vid-item div to have two "getElementById"s instead of one.

```
<DIV class="vid-item" onclick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='http://youtube.com/embed/eg6kNoJmzkY?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1',
```

document.getElementById('vid_desc').src='http://youtube.com/embed/eg6kNoJmzkY?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'">

I apologize that the html isn't pasting in properly. Also I guess I need more that 10 reputation points to post a second link, so here is it in a href

```
<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/4q3w36y27j8c9b5/Demo%20Responsive%20YouTube%20Player%20with%20Scrolling%20Thumbnail%20Playlist.htm?dl=0">dropbox link</a>
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: I've added more code, is there something I need to be more specific on?